# Auto indent when wrapping a long line to the second line

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to automate a simple indent on the second or wrapped line of names that won't fit my columns, in a very long list of individual and business names. Can't find where InDesign does that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the styling you are trying to achieve is called *hanging indent*.

That is simply done by applying a *Left Indent* and setting the *First Line Indent* to the same negative number, like this:

[image]