# Indesign: Paragraph styles. Is it possible to have a style that sets no indent for the first paragraph and 4mm for the rest of the paragraphs

Tags: adobe-indesign

Indesign: Paragraph styles. Is it possible to have a style that sets no indent for the first paragraph and 4mm for the rest of the paragraphs? What do I need to search for?

Cheers.

Comment: Is this something already set or something you are working through?

Comment: What type of style would that be? You can set styles for paragraphs, but nothing above paragraph level. How would your style know when to begin anew with no indent? If you have two styles, _Indent_ and _Non-indent_, you can set the paragraph style setting for which style to apply to the next paragraph in _Non-indent_ to be _Indent_, select all the paragraphs you want to format and hit _Apply Style [= Non-indent], Then Next Style_ – but that’s barely easier than just applying _Non-indent_ to the first paragraph and then _Indent_ to the rest.

Comment: I agree there seems to be some misunderstanding. If you meant how to have no indent on the first *line* and 4 mm on the rest of the *lines* [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/122873/84899) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks. The first paragraph has no indent but all paragraphs after that have an indent. Currently, I have a paragraph style for the first paragraph and another style for all the text underneath it. I was updating the file and making it more streamlined. Hoping I could just apply one style that could do both.

Comment: But it lies in the name that a *Paragraph Style* is only applied to a *paragraph* so you can't really make a style that works differently across different paragraphs. Having two styles to do what you want seems like the normal way to do it. How often do you need to apply that first paragraph? Once per document/chapter/page?

Comment: I guess that is the thing, I have up to four to five articles on a page. I guess I wanted to cut down on the work of two different paragraph styles. Thank you.

Comment: A way to speed it up is to assign a short-cut to the no indent style, apply the indent style to everything and then using the short-cut apply the no indent style where needed. Could take 5-20 seconds per page. (If you have something searchable in those first paragraphs you might be able to use Find/Change to apply the no indent style.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested styles to do this:
https://helpx.adobe.com/au/indesign/using/drop-caps-nested-styles.html
If this description is not clear enough, I can provide additional explanations.

Okay, I may have misspelled.
That's how it's done.

1. Create styles for the first (no indentation) and subsequent (indented) paragraphs.

[image]
[image]

2. Select the desired paragraphs, right-click on "First Paragraph" style in Paragraph Style palette, and select Apply "First Paragraph" then Next Style[image]

You can create intricately complex combinations of text in this way.